# Jenkins SSHD connection

Tags: jenkins, sshd

Having trouble finding information on using Jenkins SSHD, there's a RSA key (publickey?) supplied by the `X-Instance-Identity` header when browsing the top page.

Trouble is, it's not clear how to use this.

I've tried the obvious, and added it to `~/.ssh/id_rsa_jenkins` and then attempted to connect, after first setting the SSHD port in Jenkins config to 8822

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jenkins -p 8822 jenkins_server
```

(and alternatively)

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jenkins -p 8822 user@jenkins_server
```

However, with both of these connection attempts, I'm challenged for a passphrase, which I don't have (attempting to use the user login fails.)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure this out, from the Jenkins top page (when logged in)

```
> People > User > Configure
```

Then find **SSH Public keys**, paste the rsa/dsa public key in here and save, and you can log in.